# How to use multiple network interfaces concurrently in java?

Tags: java, network-interface

I am developing a software that needs to check the signal strength of different network interfaces like wifi, lan, dongles etc. I want to measure (absolutely or relatively) the signal strength and find out the ipaddress of all the network interfaces having strength greater than some threshold value. How can I do it in JAVA?

Comment: You can't. Java's networking APIs operate above the hardware layer.

Comment: I think you need to use C code to do that

Comment: Android or desktop/server?

Comment: @ChrisK I was thinking for java desktop but android would also work for me if its possible with android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/mytracks/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/signalstrength/SignalStrengthListenerCupcake.java.htm has some code for Android. I cannot vet it though as I work more with iOS than Android.

For the desktop, there is no pure Java solution as the JVM has not exposed this network information. If you had to go down that road you have two basic options 1) invoke the command line via java and extract the data from another command or 2) go JNI. Neither approach is portable and they both require a fair amount of effort. A variant of 1 that is available with Linux (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-wireless-network-speed-signal-strength.html) is to parse the file '/proc/net/wireless' from Java.

Sorry for not being able to give you better news. You could try sponsoring a RFC with Oracle, it does strike me as useful information to add to the JVM networking libraries.